# Mask not working if dynamically added CSS to the document header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have some blocks that have icons in the centre, created using masks and svg. It's all working fine to begin with, see the first screenshot.

Now my program loads in some settings from a  web server via ajax, which returns in some pre built css that should be replacing the svg with a different one, but instead all i am getting is a blank area where the svg should be, see image 2.

When the CSS comes back from the server jQuery is used to add it to the local document `<head>` to override the main styles.

The initial css of the loaded page that works is as follows:

```
#dashboard-items li .dashboard-icon.dashboard-icon-news span.the-icon{
    -webkit-mask: url(../img/icons/news.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
    mask: url(../img/icons/news.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
}
```

The CSS returned by the PHP code on the server by ajax call is as follows:

```
#dashboard-items li .dashboard-icon.dashboard-icon-news span.the-icon{
    -webkit-mask: url(../img/icons/placeholder.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
    mask: url(../img/icons/placeholder.svg) no-repeat center / contain;
}
```

So you can see that the CSS is pretty much the same, and placeholder.svg exists in the same local folder as news.svg - so why am I just getting a black area instead of showing the icon? If I manually edit the local CSS the icon changes fine, so the svg is clearly working.

Additionally, when I inspect in safari it says:

> The value "url(../img/icons/placeholder.svg) no-repeat center /
>   contain" is not supported for this property

It clearly is supported because I'm using it before the ajax call.

[image] [image]

Comment: Have you checked for 404s in browser console/network panel …?

Comment: You’re aware that relative URLs in CSS are relative to the location of the stylesheet, right?

Comment: Of course, i have been developing for years, so i know that the css being added is perfectly fine, i haven't ever seen this happen before. The rest of the css coming in is working perfectly, it's just this SVG that's not working. So the path ../img/icons/placeholder.svg is right for the relative location of the local document, the console is just saying The value "url(../img/icons/placeholder.svg) no-repeat center / contain" is not supported for this property - which it is because the original before the dynamic load is exactly the same

Comment: OMG you know i am being totally stupid here! I am loading in the css into the index.html file which has a different relative path to the actual css file, that's where my problem is! Man i am being stupid today. lol There we go, problem solved. Thanks for the comment!